# Passing variables to a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Using php I'm trying to pass variables to a stored procedure in MySQL. I'm getting a "white screen of death" when I click the delete button. Below is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $stmt = mssql_init('update_new_sn', $conn);

    mssql_bind($stmt, '@selectedID', $fileID, SQLINT1);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@selectedRMAID', $rmaID, SQLINT1);

    $deleteRecord = mssql_execute($stmt);

}
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `update_new_sn`//
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_new_sn`(in selectedID int, in selectedRMAID int)
begin

delete from dropbox where id = selectedID;
update rma set ref_status_id = 0 where id = selectedRMAID;

end
```

The procedure works when I test it in phpmyadmin, it successfully deletes the selected recored in the "dropbox table, and updates the rma table. So there seems to be something wrong in my block of php.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Your PHP code uses MSSQL, but your question is tagged MYSQL. Which is it?

Comment: Safe assumption if he's using phpmyadmin

Comment: So the first problem is you're trying to use the MSSQL API, but you have a MySQL database. That can't possibly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using MySQL with the mysqli API:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'CALL update_new_sn(?, ?)');
mysqli_bind_param('ii', $fileID, $rmaID);
$deleteRecord = mysqli_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: thanks for steering me in the right direction. Can you explain what (?, ?) and "ii" are doing?

Comment: Question marks are the placeholders that get filled in with the bound parameters. And `ii` means that the parameters are integers, just like  `SQLINT1` in your original attempt.